# How do you assess data validity when sample size varies over time

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size

Imagine that you have a customer feedback system where after a process people can press one of 4 buttons: (very happy, happy, sad, very sad) and an aggregation system reports how many people per hour pressed each button during each day. If the experience being measured can change during the day, and the number of people passing through it changes significantly during the day, how can you decide at what minimum hourly sample size to reject the hourly sample as unrepresentative - and how can a confidence level be expressed?

For example 3 people per hour would not be likely to yield a meaningful result; 50 people per hour may, 1000 people per hour very likely - but what's the maths here, given that the actual "experience" - eg a wait time for service - will vary during the day as well, so the average answer is not fixed?

Comment: "Unrepresentative" of what characteristic of what population? At one extreme you could reject all such data as never being unrepresentative of customers as a whole, due to biases built into the data collection procedure; at another extreme you could view these data as providing an instantaneous readout of current customer feedback results, which represent only themselves, making *all* results meaningful.

Comment: The aim is to be able to take a view on whether the feedback data for a given hour gives a reasonably balanced measure of satisfaction or not with the experience being measured at that time, or likely to be unsafe because of too small a sample in that hour. Agreed that the population of respondents is self-selecting.

Comment: Have you considered summarizing the feedback in terms of a moving window that covers a fixed number of respondents rather than a fixed duration? That would make all your measurements more comparable to each other.

Comment: That's a good idea: I think we're at the mercy of the aggregation package which comes with the system, that only reports data by the hour, but it's certainly a good suggestion.